# Como salvar um modelo com FileField usando um arquivo preexistente?

Tags: arquivo, django

Estou importando um conjunto de arquivos preexistentes pro Django, e gostaria de referenciá-los nos meus modelos (que usam `FileField` ou `ImageField`). Por exemplo, um de meus modelos é assim:

```
class Imagem(models.Model):
    arquivo = ImageField(upload_to=u"img/%Y/%m/%d")
    miniatura = ImageField(upload_to=u"img/thumb/%Y/%m/%d")
    ...
```

E eu tenho várias imagens (já copiadas pro meu `MEDIA_ROOT`) assim:

```
MEDIA_ROOT
|- gallery
   |-album1
     |-foto1.jpg
     |-foto2.jpg
     |-...
     |-thumbs
       |-thumbs_foto1.jpg
       |-thumbs_foto2.jpg
       |-...
```

(Note que as imagens não estão sob a pasta `upload_to`, mas sim em outra completamente diferente)

É possível criar instâncias desse modelo referenciando as imagens preexistentes, sem ter que fazer cópias delas e sem ter que renomeá-las e/ou movê-las? E como seria o comando para criar essas instâncias?

Eu não tenho problemas em navegar o sistema de arquivos, achar os nomes das imagens e associar cada imagem com sua miniatura, meu problema é como criar o modelo em si:

```
path_imagem = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'gallery/album1/foto1.jpg')
path_miniatura = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'gallery/album1/thumbs/thumbs_foto1.jpg')
Imagem.objects.create(???)
```

Os exemplos na documentação do Django (ex.: [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#filefield), [*"File Uploads"*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/), [*"Managing Files"*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/files/)) são todos referentes a novos arquivos, onde se cria um `File` ou se obtém um a partir de um upload, por exemplo. No meu caso os arquivos já existem e já estão sob o `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer essas referências, desde que os arquivos estejam dentro do `MEDIA_ROOT`. Basta passar o caminho **relativo** como argumento para o `objects.create`:

```
path_imagem = 'gallery/album1/foto1.jpg'
path_miniatura = 'gallery/album1/thumbs/thumbs_foto1.jpg'
Imagem.objects.create(imagem=path_imagem, miniatura=path_miniatura, ...)
```

E então o modelo referenciará o arquivo corretamente, desconsiderando o `upload_to`.

**Detalhe importante**: se for passado um caminho absoluto em vez de um relativo, o método não funcionará, *ainda que o arquivo esteja dentro do `MEDIA_ROOT`*!

```
path_imagem = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'gallery/album1/foto1.jpg')
path_miniatura = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'gallery/album1/thumbs/thumbs_foto1.jpg')
i = Imagem.objects.create(imagem=path_imagem, miniatura=path_miniatura)

print(i.imagem.path) # /var/www/vhosts/example.com/media/gallery/album1/foto1.jpg
                     # Aparentemente ok, mas...

print(i.imagem.url) # /var/www/vhosts/example.com/media/gallery/album1/foto1.jpg
                    # Deveria ser relativo ao MEDIA_URL, e não ao MEDIA_ROOT, ex.:
                    # /media/gallery/album1/foto1.jpg
                    # https://example.com/media/gallery/album1/foto1.jpg
                    # etc
```

É preciso um caminho relativo para que a URL seja montada corretamente.

Fonte: *[Set an ImageField path in Django manually](https://andrewbrookins.com/tech/set-the-path-to-an-imagefield-in-django-manually/)*